# difference between pen and *pen in this code

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
int main(void)
{

    char mine[5] = "hello";
    char *pen = mine;

    while(*pen != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n", *pen);
        pen++;
    }


}



int main(void)
{

    char mine[5] = "hello";
    char *pen = mine;

    while(*pen != '\0')
    {
        printf("%c\n", *pen);
        *pen++;
    }


}
```

I'm trying to grasp the idea of pointers with string. I ran both of the codes and got the same result, but I got a warning on the 2nd version of the code with *pen++ but still was able to run. 
What is each of them doing and how come it gave me the same output?

Comment: Please note that `char mine[5] = "hello";` lacks the null terminator that the code is looking for. It would need to be `char mine[6] = "hello";` or `char mine[] = "hello";`

Answer (score 3):

According to the rules on [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the line

`*pen++;`

is equivalent to

`*(pen++);`

which means the `*` does nothing. So it is doing exactly the same thing as the line

`pen++;`

in the first program.

Also, it is important to note that the line

`char mine[5] = "hello";`

is not doing what you expect. You are initializing a character array of length 5 with a string literal of length 6 (including the terminating null character). This means the array does not contain sufficient space for the terminating null character.

Therefore, you should change the line to the following:

`char mine[6] = "hello";`

Alternatively, in order to make the compiler automatically allocate a sufficient amount of memory for the initialization, you can just write the following:

`char mine[] = "hello";`

Comment: Please note that `char mine[5] = "hello";` **is** valid C. There is no reason why an array *has* to be a string. What is invalid, is string operations that rely on the missing null terminator.

Comment: `char mine[5] = "hello";` is valid C per C 2018 6.7.9 14: “… Successive bytes of the string literal (**including the terminating null character if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks for quoting the C standard, you have convinced me. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`pen++;` is a statement consisting of one expression `pen++`. This expression's value is `pen` and the side effect is that `pen` is incremented.

`*pen++` is a statement constisting of one expression `*pen++`. The expression's value is `*pen` and the side effect is that `pen` is incremented.

When an expression is used as a statement, then the value of the expression is ignored, only the side effects are relevant/observable. So in your case it is irrelevant if `pen` or `*pen` is the value, the side effect of incrementing `pen` is identical in both cases. Thus in your program both variants have the same observable effect. Yet it does not make sense to write `*pen++` if you don't want to use the value. Then you should just write `pen++`, or even better `++pen`.